# Number of random variables required such that their sum exceeds a threshold

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, asymptotics

Consider a sequence of independent and identically distributed random variables $X_{1},X_{2}, \ldots$ such that the mean $E[X_{i}] = \mu$ and variance $\operatorname {Var}[X_{i}] = \sigma^{2}$ are finite. Let $B$ be a constant.

Define $K = \min\{k: \sum_{i=1}^{k}X_{i} > B\}$.

Is there a way to characterize the asymptotic distribution of $K$ (i.e., for large values of $B$)?

Comment: Yes, although I'll comment rather than answering since I'm a little rusty on the details. Essentially, due to the central limit theorem, on long timescales, the random walk will look like Brownian motion. So for large $B$ the distribution of $K$ will look like a Brownian first passage time distribution.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you add any more details? I am not sure how to apply central limit theorem in this case.

Comment: The fact that I can't really fill in the details is why I left a comment rather than an answer. I don't have a lot of time right now, but perhaps someone else will jump in or I will later. If you are unfamiliar with how random walks with finite variance have Brownian motion as a continuum limit, there is a lot of stuff you can read about that. Googling 'random walk continuum limit' gave this as a result: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-366-random-walks-and-diffusion-fall-2006/lecture-notes/lec08.pdf